# Filter doesn't work as the way I idealized in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I'm trying to filter an array of objects *(filteredListing)* by an array of numbers *(filters['bedroomCount'])*. I need those items which bedroomCount equals to one of the numbers in the array. The log correctly outputs the booleans, but the if statement is not working. What could be the problem?

```
   this.filteredListing = this.filteredListing.filter(item => {
      if(this.filters['bedroomCount'].length === 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        this.filters['bedroomCount'].forEach(elem => {
          console.log(`${item['bedroomCount']}-${elem}  ${item['bedroomCount'] === elem}`)
          if(item['bedroomCount'] === elem) return true;
          else return false;
        });
      }
    });
```

Comment: You're not returning anything in your `else`

Comment: You likely want `.some` instead of `.forEach`, but it's hard to tell. There's an `elem` that's equal to a number? What's an `item`? Sample input and output? Naming things is important....

Comment: @Natixco you have *nested* if statements, and in the else clause of the outer one *you don't return anything*. Those inner returns are for the forEach callback, not the filter function. You *likely* want something like `return this.filters['bedroomCount'].some(...` As an added aside, try to avoid the temptation to write inline callbacks that do non-trivial logic: you can't test them!

Comment: `forEach()` returns `undefined`

Comment: Yeah, got it working with some! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fairly easy fix here:

```
this.filteredListing = this.filteredListing.filter(item => {
  if(this.filters['bedroomCount'].length === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return this.filters['bedroomCount'].some(elem => {
      if(item['bedroomCount'] === elem) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

But that doesn't fix the thing that caused the error in the first place: the lack of `return` was hard to spot and hard to test! Let's fix that. Since we're using `this` I'm assuming we've got a class, so let's add a method encoding the filtering logic:

```
filterByBedroomCount (item) {
  // It's a lot to type over and over so we'll pull it out.
  const ct = this.filters.bedroomCount;
  // Added bonus, the conditional logic fits readably on to
  // one line now.
  return ct.some(elem => item.bedroomCount === elem);
}
```

Note that I've also tightened up the conditional logic, you didn't really need the conditional statements when the values themselves are truthy/falsey. It helps that `.some` on an empty array will always return false meaning you don't even need the length check. Now you can pass in a mock item to the method in a unit test to make sure it does what you want.